# Elementary Os. Nvidia and apt-get stopped working after updating windows 8.1 (Dual boot)

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, nvidia, dpkg, elementary-os

My computer have dual boot (Windows 8.1 and Elementary OS Freya  - Ubuntu 14.04).
Today, After installing updates on my windows partition Elementary OS loaded into a black screen.
I've already encountered problems with my nvidia driver before, so I've tried to enter the terminal (ctl+alt+f1/7) and re-install the nvidia drivers.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

But then I got the error message `apt-get syntax error "(" unexpected`

I've tried to enter recovery mode and repair dpkg, but it seems dpkg was corrupted somehow.

I'm fairly new to Linux, and I'm having hard time diagnosing the problem (not to mention, Solve it). is it the nvidia driver? dpkg? or maybe something else (or all combined?)

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: First try `sudo apt-get clean` and then `sudo apt-get update` and tell us if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. unfortunately it didn't helped. I've also just now re installed  Elementary OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia\*
```

instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the error  apt-get syntax error "(" unexpected.